# why is my for loop expected showing identifier error?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
//Prompt user for valid input
int n;
do
{
    n = get_int("height: ");
}
while (n < 0 || n > 23);
}
//drawing pyramid
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
printf(" ")
}
```

when I  enter make mario the following occurs in my terminal...

```
error: expected identifier or '(' 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
^
```

does anybody know why this error message is coming up in my code? why is this being flagged? does the green (^) arrow below the "for" error mean the program does not want me to use a for loop?

Comment: What programming language is that? Also, your error (with semicolons) does not match your code (with commas) in the for statement, which version yields which error?

Comment: Please post the code in the lines before the "for" statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a comma “,” instead of a colon “;”.

In for loops, use colons “;” to divide between the separate declarations.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response.

Comment: I have just tried that but am still getting the same thing

Comment: error: expected identifier or '('
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
while (n < 0 || n > 23);
}
```

You have an extra }. Remove it and your code should compile. Every opening { needs exactly one closing }.

Also think about correct indentation. That helps you see such mistakes.